# Webpack: how to bundle entries to multiple common chunks with CommonsChunkPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Say I have two pages `Page1` and `Page2`, both of them use some library(vendors) like `jquery` `backbone` which I want to be extracted as a single file, then I want the shared modules(exclude the vendors) to be extracted in another single file, this is the webpack config:

```
function listFiles(srcpath) {
    return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
    });
}
var createEntry = function (src) {
    var dest = {
        vendor: ["backbone", "underscore"]
    };
    var files = listFiles(src);
    files.forEach(function (dir) {
        var name = dir;
        dest[name] = src + "/" + dir + "/entry.js";
    });
    return dest;
};

//each sub directory contains a `entry.js` as the entry point for the page
var entries = createEntry("./app/pages");//    {vender:['jquery','backbone'],page1:'src/page1/entry.js',page2:'src/page2/entry.js'    }

var config = {
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./app/'),
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.js", Infinity),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            filename: 'common.js',
            minChunks: 2
        })
    ],
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        path: './../main/webapp/static/dist',
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/static/dist'
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

However with the above config:

`common.js` contains webpack runtime,

`page1.js`  contains page1 specified modules  and shared modules

`page2.js`  contains page2 specified modules  and shared modules

Which means `page1.js` and `page2.js` contains too many repeat codes.

Then I tried to change the config:

```
var entries = createEntry("./app/pages");
var chunks = [];
for (var k in entries) {
    if (k === 'vendor')
        continue;
    chunks.push(k);
}


new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.js", Infinity),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',
    filename: 'common.js',
    minChunks: 2,
    chunks:chunks
}),
```

Then

`common.js` contains the webpack runtime and the vendor libraries, and the shared modules

`vendor.js` contains the webpack runtime and the vendor libraries.

`page1.js`  contains page1 specified modules

`page2.js`  contains page2 specified modules

It seems it get closer, but the `common.js` should not contain the vendors

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 14):

If you want multiple common chunk bundles, you'll have to specify all chunks details for each common bundle like shown [in the example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-commons-chunks#user-content-webpackconfigjs):

```
var config = {

    entry: {
        vendor: ["backbone", "underscore"],
        common: "./app/pages/common/entry.js",
        page1: "./app/pages/page1/entry.js",
        page2: "./app/pages/page2/entry.js"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            chunks: ["vendor"]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "common",
            chunks: ["common"]
        })        
    ]
};
```

Note that the `chunks` option of `CommonsChunkPlugin` refers to the name of the entries you target. As you want to split `vendor` from `common`, you have to explicitly say that you only want `vendor` entry in `vendor` common-chunk and same for `common`.

Comment: How has this approach changed in Webpack 4?

Comment: @mmmeff yes, CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed and you must use splitChunks now https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/